# NoReverseMatch at /create_blog/ Reverse for 'update_blog' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['update_blog/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: django

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yr8H.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt6en.png)

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE289.png)

[link_to_update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1JDy.png)

[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJi43.png)

PLEASE TYPE THE CODE DOWN AND TELL THE REASON AND PLEASE SEND IT

Comment: (1) Please don't post your code as images. (2) Please don't SHOUT AT US.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [“What topics can I ask about here?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [“What types of questions should I avoid asking?”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read (the Stack Overflow question checklist)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922]. You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You're doing

```
{% url "update_blog" forms.id %}
```

but the parameter is named `id` in your urls.py mapping.

That means you'll need to do

```
{% url "update_blog" id=forms.id %}
```

Comment: hey same error man

Comment: The "not working" link hints that `forms.id` is not a thing for you.

Comment: can u check views.py and tell me what to do

Comment: can u check all the links and tell me the code change

Comment: Looks like `forms.id` should maybe be `form.instance.id`. But no, I'm not quite inclined to "check all the links" for you.

Comment: what should i do not able to solve the problem , it would be a great help if u can

Comment: You should think harder about what the problem is, step by step. E.g. try doing `The value is [[[{{ forms.id }}]]]` if that helps you - if you see `[[[]]]` you know there's no `forms.id`.